# Moonlight in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, moonlight

What is the preferred way to install moonlight in Debian (Testing)? I searched the repositories, but there seems to nothing relevant. Also this wiki:

http://wiki.debian.org/Teams/DebianMonoGroup/Moonlight

just states its out of date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the instructions on the official Moonlight website. Go [here](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx).

In short, the steps are:

1. Download the latest version (3.99 as of now) since you are using Debian Sid.
2. Iceweasel (or Epiphany) may give you a security warning. Basically, you need to allow http://www.go-mono.com to install add-ons. So, change the options so that this is possible.

And you are done!

Comment: `Novel Moonlight could not be installed because its not compatible with Iceweasel 5.0`

Comment: @Grzenio, are you able to install the stable version (2.4)? I'll try this out on my Squeeze machine later and let you know more...